# Shortcut an execution when a list becomes longer than previous answers

Tags: prolog

I have a prolog code that basically tries to generate the solutions for a problem with a lot of possible solutions (each solution is returned as a list of items). Since the resolution is expensive and I'm only interested into knowing the most efficient solution (ie the one with the lowest length), I would like to shortcut the execution when a new answer becomes larger or equal to the smallest one I already have.

I would do something like this, but it requires knowing the maximal size beforehand:

```
solve_problem_efficiently(Solutions, MaxSize) :-
    solve_problem(Solutions),
    length(Solutions),
    Length < MaxSize.
```

What's the best way to achieve this effect in Prolog?

Comment: You can pass a max length as a parameter to `solve_problem`, and you can use an iterative strategy where you start with a low limit and then increase it if you do not get any results.

Comment: That's something I'm trying to do, but it makes it impossible to get a solution fast. Any valid solution will probably have about 100 items, but even trying to generate single-digit-sized lists takes more and more time before eventually yielding false.

Comment: Worth nothing that my database contains a few tens of thousands of facts.

Comment: The question is not meaningful as it is. There is no magical Prolog function that can automatically notice when you are not on a path to a solution in some general sense. There are lots of things you can do for any specific problem. Post some real code if you want better help.

Comment: Look up `length/2` in the Prolog documentation.